# Shown the next button of a quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm doing a quiz only when the user answer the question the next button  shown, but i cant hide that button when the question is not answered.

html:

```
<div id="navContent">
    <button type="image"  class="hide"></button>
</div>
```

js:

```
if(this.id==rnd) {
    $('button.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
}
```

and CSS:

```
.button {
     position:relative;
     background-image:url(img/bouton.png);
     border:none;
     width:111px;
     height:202px;
     color:white;
}

.button:hover {
  background-image:url(img/bouton1.png);
  width:111px;
  height:202px;
}
.hide { dispaly: none; }
```

Comment: your `display:none` at `.hide` class is misspelled!

Answer (score 1):

Its already working- there is a typo in the styles for `display`. 
See snippet below:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
      $(this).addClass('hide');
  });
```

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
  border: none;
  width: 111px;
  height: 202px;
  color: white;
}
.button:hover {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
  width: 111px;
  height: 202px;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navContent">
  <button type="image">Hide me!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. All buttons should get the `display: none;` attribute except the first one.

   ```
   button {
    display: none;
   }
   ```

   First button tag:

   ```
   <button style="display: block;"> ... </button>
   ```
2. If the button is clicked hide all buttons at all and display: block the next one like this:

   ```
   $('button').on('click', function(){
    $('button').css('display', 'hide');
    $(this).next('button').css('display', block');
   });
   ```
3. If you answere the last one you should recognize it, see here.

   ```
   $('button').on('click', function(){        
    if($(this) != $('button').last()){
     $('button').css('display', 'hide');
     $(this).next('button').css('display', 'block');
    }
    else {
     // finished quiz
    }
   });
   ```